# Can't inside more than 1 time C++

Tags: c++

What's wrong with my code. I want to add data 10 times and view details, but I can't do it. Could anyone help me with this?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void load_menu(void);
void analysis(void);
void details(void);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    load_menu();
    return 0;
}
void load_menu(void)
{
    int choice;

    while (1)
        {
            cout<<"*******************************************************************************\n";
            cout<<"*                           Welcome to SYSTEM analyze                         *\n";
            cout<<"*******************************************************************************\n\n";

            cout<<"           Welcome to SYSTEM analyze \n\n";
            cout<<"1.Voter Analysis 1\n2.Voter Details 2\n3.Exit 3\n\n";
            cout<<"*******************************************************************************\n";
            cout<<"Please enter your Choose : ";cin>>choice;
            switch(choice)
                {
                case 1 :
                    analysis();
                    break;
                case 2: details();
                    break;
                case 3: cout<<"Going out !\n";
                    exit(1) ;
                    break;
                default: cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
                    cout<<"*******************************************************************************\n";
                    cout<<"*                          PLEASE INSERT AGAIN  !!                            *\n";
                    cout<<"*******************************************************************************\n\n";
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";
                    break;
                }

        }

}

void analysis(void)
{
    char voterid[10];
    char votername[30];
    char voteraddr[30];
    char phone[15];
    int age;
    char status[20];
    {
        cout<<"get voterid";
        cin>>voterid;
        cout<<"voter's name";
        cin>>votername;
        cout<<"voter's address";
        cin>>voteraddr;
        cout<<"phone number";
        cin>>phone;
        cout<<"voter's age";
        cin>>age;
        if(age>18)
            strcpy(status,"eligible");
        else
            strcpy(status,"not eligible");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++);
    }
}
void details(void)
{
    char voterid[10];
    char votername[30];
    char voteraddr[30];
    char phone[15];
    int age;
    char status[20];
    {
        cout<<"voter's information\n";
        cout<<"--------------------\n";
        cout<<"voter id:"<<voterid<<"\n";
        cout<<"voter name:"<<votername<<"\n";
        cout<<"voter addr:"<<voteraddr<<"\n";
        cout<<"phone no:"<<phone<<"\n";
        cout<<"voter's age:"<<age<<"\n";
        cout<<"status:"<<status<<"\n";
        cout<<"-----------------\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything in the `for` loop.

Comment: Your variables are all local to each function. When you set `voterid` in `analysis`, it won't be visible in `details`. You either have to put these in a structure that you return from one function and pass to another, or use global variables.

Comment: If you want to add multiple datas, you need to make an array of structures to contain all of them. You're really missing some fundamental concepts, I don't think SO is the appropriate forum to try to teach you the basics of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in this code:

- All your variables voterid[10]; votername[30]; voteraddr[30]; phone[15]; age; status[20] are local to function `analysis` and function `details`. So the data you store in those variables from `analysis` function is not getting accessed in `details`. So, make those variables global.
- In `analysis`, you have put `for` statement at wrong place. The `for` loop is not iterating. That's why you are not able to insert data more than once.
- In `details`, there is no `for` loop to get the data from array.
- `voterid` is an array. So, put value in it using the index - like: `voterid[i]` where `i` is the index.
- You may use `iostream` instead of `iostream.h` in header file.